# Placeholders and Boolean Logic in Data-Table Filters

Tags: magento2, backend, filter

I can filter a data-table in the backend by a custom search term for textual columns, see [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/pattern-library/filters/data-table-filters/filtering.html#filter-by-search).
Can I somehow use placeholders or logical operations (like `not` or `xor`) therein?

I have tried `*` as a placeholder as well as `NOT` and `!` as a prefix to a single search term and `AND`, `&`, `OR` and `|` as combinators between two terms – all without any success at all.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/283